# How to trim video of duration more than 30 seconds in iOS?

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, avvideocomposition

I want to select video from gallery but user can only choose video upto 30 seconds from the app.

so how to achieve video trimming for certain amount of time?

By using AVFoundation I have done till selecting the video but i don't know how to trim the video?

Is there any third party library or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to select/trim video 30 second from the gallery.

```
func selecteVideoFromGallery() {
       let controller = UIImagePickerController()
       controller.sourceType = .photoLibrary
       controller.videoMaximumDuration = 30.00
       controller.allowsEditing = true
       controller.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
       controller.delegate = self
       controller.isEditing = true
       present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```